# Working script after closing session

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I use Amazon EC2.
I connect by SSH and run python script. If I exit, will it continues working?
How can I run Python script, close SSH session and he's been working on?

Comment: can you provide some more details on code..u need to run python script after exiting from ssh session right???

Comment: I connect by SSH and run python script (python example.py). Script are working. I want to script will be working after my closing session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before your script use nohup command
(nohup python example.py).the output will be stored in nohup.out in ur execution folder.