# Forking "sbt run &"

Tags: sbt, fork

I cannot fork my `sbt` process using `sbt run &`. When I do so, I return to bash console, and I get a PID, but soon, the process stops.

In my `build.sbt` I have added the line `Keys.fork in run := true` but that doesn't do anything.

What is that?

Comment: found the actual answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803734/most-appropriate-method-to-persist-a-sbt-process-after-exiting-ssh-session#answer-39898170. Add the unsupported terminal java argument `sbt -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal about &`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you need to restrict to `run`. Try just

```
fork := true
```

Comment: Then either you're putting it in the wrong place or your config is doing something funky. Create a minimal project on github that demonstrates your problem so people can investigate further.

Comment: Oh hold on, are you literally typing `sbt run&` on the command line? Because that's not at all what Forking is in the SBT context. Fork in SBT in for when you run things from the interactive console. I think you might be looking for sbt-native-packager.